# Grouping variables together

Tags: r, grouping

I have a data set that I would like to do some r statistical modelling on. The machine that I am using has 40 pallets, each with 8 positions. Each pallet cycles through the machine and checks are done at two stations with the results recorded. Each Station has 10 positions as well. I want to be able to group together the Pallet ID and the Pallet position ID's, but am unsure how to achieve this.
Below is a representation of the data from Pallet 1, but this will be similar across all 40 pallets

```
Pallet  Position    Station Result  
1   1   101 0.234   1st Cycle
1   2   205 0.3244  1st Cycle
1   3   102 0.1123  1st Cycle
1   4   206 0.4321  1st Cycle
1   5   103 0.5688  1st Cycle
1   6   207 0.6554  1st Cycle
1   7   104 0.9988  1st Cycle
1   8   208 0.4354  1st Cycle
1   1   107 0.55    2nd Cycle
1   2   201 0.5356  2nd Cycle
1   3   108 0.2245  2nd Cycle
1   4   202 0.0994  2nd Cycle
1   5   109 0.0333  2nd Cycle
1   6   203 0.429   2nd Cycle
1   7   110 0.32333 2nd Cycle
1   8   204 0.33    3rd Cycle
1   1   103 0.32444 3rd Cycle
1   2   207 0.555   3rd Cycle
1   3   104 0.9870987   3rd Cycle
1   4   208 0.555   3rd Cycle
1   5   105 0.346   3rd Cycle
1   6   209 0.234   3rd Cycle
1   7   106 0.689   3rd Cycle
1   8   210 0.0944  3rd Cycle
```

So I would like to do some time series with them. By being able to group together as follows

Pallet 1 Position 1 station 101 against result

But I need to get all pallets and all pallet positions against the stations and then compare the results to see if the results are above or below certain values. i.e. below 0.25 is a fail or above 0.75 is a fail, but any result between these is a pass

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: thanks @r2evans I have edited

Comment: What do you want to do once they're grouped? Are you just trying to sort? Or do you want to group and summarize the results? You might want to look at the `dplyr` package, specifically the `group_by` and `summarize` functions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8366499/divibisan  would like to do time series analysis after I get to sort them correctly